# How to detect Login from another device in PHP or Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, detect

Let's Suppose
I have my example account on example.com. When I log in, it should save my device for the next time when I came back and login it will verify me and my device. No matter what browser it is, mean when I did it the first time, I was using Chrome and now I am doing it on Firefox Like this.

But someone got my creds OR I myself gave creds to someone and he try login into my account then it should detect his new device.

Comment: You probably want to go research the keyword “device fingerprinting”.

Answer (score 1):

Check your cookie identifier (e.g. logged = hash(user_id), etc) in browser. If it is not there, it means that it is a new device. So you can take action and store your identifier in the browser cookie at the same time.

Edit: In my old project, I solve it like this:

```php
    const COOKIE_NAME = "device_code";

    public function login()
    {
        $cookieValue = bcrypt(auth()->id());
        if (request()->cookie(self::COOKIE_NAME) != $cookieValue) {
            // new device
            // do some stuff
            // if allowed save cookie
            request()->cookie(self::COOKIE_NAME, $cookieValue, $minutes = 60 * 24 * 30);

            return $response;
        }

        // do login logic
        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: What if the user uses another browser.

Comment: Usually, another browser is considered a different device. But when you need to literally identify a device, either the device's fingerprint or IP address is used. However, in principle, both options are very unreliable. (Fingerprint option is currently blocked in most cases and the IP address is often shared by many users, or various other methods of NAT / routing).